# POST request in tcp non blocking server in C++

Tags: c++, http, tcp, http-post

I have this fuction to deal with clients POST request :

```
ostringstream postRequest(int index, vector<string>parsed, int* statusCode, string* content)
{
    string fileName = parsed[1];
    if (fileName == "/")
    {
        fileName = "/index.html";
    }

    string tmpString(sockets[index].buffer);
    int position = tmpString.find("<");
    *content = tmpString.substr(position);
    ostringstream oStrSVar;
    ifstream f(".\\files" + fileName);
    // Check if file opened
    if (f.good())
    {
        *statusCode = 204;
        oStrSVar << "HTTP/1.1 " << *statusCode << " No Content\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        *statusCode = 201;
        oStrSVar << "HTTP/1.1 " << *statusCode << " Created\r\n";
        oStrSVar << "Content-Location: files" + fileName << "\r\n";

    }
    f.close();

    //Writing the new content to file
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(".\\files" + fileName);
    myfile << *content;
    myfile.close();

    return oStrSVar;


}
```

The problem is when I rum my code I get a runtime error. I added some prints to check where is the error and this is this line :

```
*content = tmpString.substr(position);
```

I send my request with postman this way :
[image]
I can't understand why my code isn't working and I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not `C`.  ( `vector<string>parsedvector<string>parsed` )  _I get a runtime error_.  What is the runtime error?.  And the picture does not really add value to the post.  And in this statement: `*content = tmpString.substr(position);` it appears you are attempting to assign the string to the value located at `content`.  maybe `strcpy(content, tmpString.substr(position));` would work better.

Comment: You should attach a debugger to your program. It sure can help.

Comment: This is not a valid HTTP response. It has at least the header end (empty line, i.e. `\r\n`) missing.